# Rewrinting php url to friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Everything works fine, but my page.php-line will not work.

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpg|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule  ^blog/category/(.*)$/?$ bcategory.php?slug=$1   [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)$/?$              page.php?slug=$1       [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^news/(.*)$/?$          news.php?slug=$1       [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^service/(.*)$/?$       service.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^search                 search.php             [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^404                    404.html             [NC,L]
```

Expected result: page.php?slug=about-us | (www.example.com)/about-us

Comment: Your `$/?$` is strange, there can only be one ending. Just do `/?$` then the `/` at the end is optional. The will capture all other rules though. Maybe you want `[^/]+`

Answer (score 0):

Move this page.php-line bottom (after 404 rule) and change to:
`RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ page.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]`